# Two variables with the same value in Python

Tags: python

In neural network, I have come across a line like this one:

```
W_grad,b_grad = grad_fn(X_train,y_train,W,b)
```

I don't understand what the above means. Is it a shorthand for

```
W_grad = grad_fn(X_train,y_train,W,b)
b_grad = grad_fn(X_train,y_train,W,b)  ?
```

Comment: ``grad_fn`` returns 2 objects, each one is assigned to ``W_grad`` and ``b_grad`` respectively.

Comment: `grad_fn` returns a tuple, and the pair of values is spread to the two variables.

Comment: This is why it is very important to learn python before trying to use any library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's called *unpacking* (look it up, it's common in python)

It's shorthand for

```py
W_grad = grad_fn(X_train,y_train,W,b)[0]
b_grad = grad_fn(X_train,y_train,W,b)[1]
```

It will only work if `grad_fn(...)` returns an *iterable* with two elements, otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means grad_fn(X_train,y_train,W,b) have 2 values that distributed to W_grad and b_grad.

For the example, if I declare these variables:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

it means a has value of 1 and b has value of 2

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it,

```
W_grad,b_grad = grad_fn(X_train,y_train,W,b)
```

is shorthand for

```
W_grad = grad_fn(X_train,y_train)
b_grad = grad_fn(W,b)
```